# Rails & Neo4j - background processing and or queue - DelayedJob, SideKiq, RabbitMQ, Resque - which will fill these requirements?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rabbitmq, delayed-job, resque, sidekiq

I have some Neo4j cypher queries that take quite a bit of time to process (they aggregate data)..  I've optimized them to death, but they still take longer than I want.. (Using Rails 3.2, Rest (Neography gem), Ruby 1.93, Neo4j 1.98, Mac OSX 10.7  )

For example, when a user comments on an object, I fan out updates to all of their friends.  Right now the fan out process is attached to the comment process, and I need to separate it out, otherwise the user who comments waits longer than necessary..  And I need to **guarantee** the job will be run and not lost or never executed, even if the whole system has to be rebooted.

So my first question is, does what I want actually require a message queue and a background processing tool, or can both of these be found in one system.  I.e.,  Might this be a case of needing a message queue to guarantee a job is executed, but then using a background process to execute the job?

Secondly, what system(s) will meet my requirements?

Here are my requirements, in order of priority:

1. **Run in the background.**  The act of commenting will kick off a job to be executed later/or as a separate process
2. **Guarantee execution**.  Even if I reboot the servers and the queue, it must carry out the task when everything is back up..
3. **Doesn't require ActiveRecord for MY data**.. I'm not using ActiveRecord at all - so any candidate can't require my data to be  in an activerecord source.  The queue etc could be in activerecord, but none of my data is..
4. **Multiple queues**:   Some queues are more important than others - they have higher priority  - so I should be able to give more cpu time to certain queues
5. **Scalable**:   Needs to be able to run multiple processes/threads (Like Sidekiq)
6. **Distributed**:  Can run jobs on different servers/cluster
7. **Easy to Implement**:  I don't want to write tons of code to get what I already have working in some other system.
8. **Admin interface**:  Would be nice to have a gui of some sort to work with.

Please, I'm not asking for fanboy answers or a flame wars, nor answers from 2007.. Looking for 2014 info..

I am aware there is SideKiq, RabbitMQ, and DelayedJob, Resque etc...  Please tell me what you have found to be the strengths and weaknesses of each system - or any other system - based upon recent experience with recent versions, and why one in particular meets these requirements.

Finally It doesn't matter which one(s) are "better" overall but rather, which one best fits these needs from a technical perspective.

Comment: Well, `delayed_job` and `resque` you've already ruled out per your multithreading requirement. Sidekiq will give you an admin interface, multi-threading, multiple queues with prioritisation, backgrounding,  guaranteed execution, and no ActiveRecord dependency. Other than that think about using something like Pusher or Firebase.

Comment: Is there any real performance advantage to multi-threading?   I'm not sure all my resources are thread safe.. The reason I want multi-threading is my presumption that it is faster / can handle more work than processes..

Comment: Well, one of the reasons Sidekiq shines is multithreading. It allows you to use a single heroku worker (or any server) to perform multiple jobs simultaneously. Whereas doing a job with delayed_job or resque requires a single process. So the performance advantage is quite substantial in terms of cost and time, at least.

Comment: Ok.. but won't jobs be lost of Redis goes down? (Maybe use Redis Sentinel? but can't that go down as well... or kevinzen/sidekiq-multi-redis-client and use two redis sources).  If so, should I just use a message queue and then hand off jobs to sidekiq?

Comment: Anything you use has the potential to go down, not just redis. You can setup redis with a master/slave config to mitigate this issue. If one instance goes down another will pick up the slack. In theory there is not such thing as a failsafe system, but you can get pretty close.

Comment: Also, if redis goes down, Sidekiq will run the jobs after it goes back up. I have a pretty simplistic setup and have never lost a job even when redis went down (too many connections, so the whole system went down--after increasing the connection pool everything went back to normal and sidekiq cleared out the job queues).